# What is the longest game that yields result finally

Tags: international-sports

Are there any sports other than Test Cricket played over the course of five days to achieve a result? Even in Cricket, the match may end in a draw, which means no result is obtained. But, is there any sport available, that takes as long to play and achieves a result at the end?

Comment: Are you only asking about cricket? or any sport?

Comment: @waxeagle I am talking about sports that is played too long like Test Cricket

Comment: How long is "too long?" Why is Test Cricket played "too long?"

Answer (score 1):

In tennis, John Isner defeated Nicholas Mahut 6–4, 3–6, 6–7(7–9), 7–6(7–3), 70–68 in the first round of the 2010 Wimbledon Championships after 11 hours 5 minutes, played over three days.<sub>[(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isner%E2%80%93Mahut_match_at_the_2010_Wimbledon_Championships)</sub>

Please note that this is an extremely rare corner case, but fits the definition of "played too long to achieve result."

Comment: That's still two days short of a test cricket match.